# How to add action in wordpress custom plugin?

Tags: hooks

I have added below code in custom plugin functions.php file but it is not display after header.

How to display custom breadcrumb after header?

```
add_action('generate_after_header', function () {
    echo do_shortcode('[flexy_breadcrumb]');
});
```

Comment: Where did you get the action name "generate_after_header" from? I don't see that in WordPress core or any of the default themes.

Comment: This is a Generatepress theme hook

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the theme or child-theme, you could add your own hook with [do_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) in the appropriate template files and then hook onto that with your `add_action()`.

Comment: need to add add_action() in plugin, where should i add?

Comment: If it's a plugin you've written yourself you can add it immediately after the initial file comment.